# IIS7 not having access to web.config

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis-7

I have published a .net 4.0 web app. I am trying to configure IIS7 to show my app and I created a new application pool with .net framework 4.0 configuration.

Then, I created a new app and pointed to the virtual directory. I went to the URL and I see a blank page. Trying to configure default pages resulted on an error:

[image: IIS Error]

I think I am having a permission error on the virtual directory. I gave full control to users IUSR and "Everyone" but nothing changed. Any help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think so, this is a local environment and I have to deploy on IIS as a part of my development process

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is an access issue.

You should try...

1. Download Process Monitor from Microsoft Download site.
2. Run the tool
3. Reproduce the issue
4. Press CTRL+E (stop capturing output) in Process Monitor
5. Search for "Access Denied"

Allow appropriate access.

Also, run IIS as Local Administrator.